# Service Locator: Get all exports

Tags: c#, mef, service-locator

I'm using *MEF* and I have two exports having the same contract type but with different contract name

Eg:

```
[Export("TypeA", typeof(MyPlugin))]
[Export("TypeB", typeof(MyPlugin))]
```

I could retrieve each exports using its respective contract name:

```
ServiceLocator.GetExportedValues<MyPlugin>("TypeA");
```

But now I wish to retrieve all instances implementing `MyPlugin`. is there any way I could do it?

I've tried using the following code:

```
ServiceLocator.GetExportedValues<MyPlugin>();
```

But it did not work. Apparently it is used to retrieve only implementations with no specific contract name.

Any opinion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would simply add a nameless export alongside every named export if you want it to be resolvable both ways. For example

```
// named and nameless
[Export("TypeA", typeof(MyPlugin))]
[Export(typeof(MyPlugin))]

// named nameless, again
[Export("TypeB", typeof(MyPlugin))]
[Export(typeof(MyPlugin))]

class MyPlugin { }


[TestMethod]
public void mef()
{
    var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(this.GetType().Assembly);
    var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

    Assert.AreEqual(2, container.GetExportedValues<MyPlugin>().Count());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strongly typed Metadata export.

1. Create a custom attribute inherited from ExportAttribute, which implements from a interface.
2. Use this custom attribute instead of Export.

You can use Import to get the required type.

```
[ImportMany]
public IEnumerable<Lazy<YourType,IMetadataAttribute>> Plugins{get;private set;}
```

You can get futher information from [MEF Documentation](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata)

Answer (score 0):

Declare both types of `Export`

```
[Export(typeof(IFoo)),Export("TypeA", typeof(IFoo))]
public class Foo1 : IFoo { }

[Export(typeof(IFoo)),Export("TypeB", typeof(IFoo))]
public class Foo2 : IFoo { }
```

And import them using `ImportMany`

```
[ImportMany]
IFoo[] foos;
```

Comment: How is this answer any different than @default.kramer's?

Comment: The declaration is the same, yet I also show you how you can have Mef inject all instances without having to reference the container/catalog directly... which is the proper way how one should use a DI framework.